# Как в меню переполнения возле текста пункта меню добавить "Switch" переключатель

Tags: android, меню, android-toolbar, виджет

Нужно в меню переполнения тулбара добавить пункт выпадающего списка, который будет состоять из текста и переключателя.
Не `CheckBox` или `RadioButton`, а именно с `Switch`.

Пробовал добавлять в `item`такое поле:  `app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"` чтобы вывести `Switch`.

Перепробовал несколько конструкций:

**menu:**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="Поделиться" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/favorite"
    android:title="Добавить в избранное" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/has_switched"
    android:title="Текст"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
    />
```

**switch_layout №1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Switch 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

**switch_layout №2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Switch 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

**switch_layout №3:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Switch 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/switch_my"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Так же пробовал через `group`:

```
<group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/has_switched"
        android:title="Текст"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout" />
</group>
```

Если сделать так:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/has_switched"
        android:title="Текст"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout" />
</group>
```

то получаю `checkbox`.

Подскажите как можно впихнуть в элемент меню переключатель `Switch`?

---

**UPD:** Под вопросом "КАК МОЖНО...?" я имел ввиду "КАК можно это сделать?". То что таких методов "из коробки" нет - знаю, но верю что не один я этим вопросом задавался.

Буду премного благодарен если кто-то подскажет какую-то либу, или  ссылку на аналогичную проблему может скинуть.

Answer (score 0):

В документации о меню переполнения идет речь о поддержке только варианта `CheckBox`.

Comment: К сожалению, я знаю о том что там возможны только CheckBox, RadioButton либо субменю. О том что мне это не подходит, я написал в начале вопроса.

Comment: Я видел, что такой вариант вам не подходит. Я отвечал на последний вопрос "Подскажите как можно впихнуть в элемент меню переключатель Switch?", и ссылался на документацию, в которой сказано, что Switch не поддерживается, и собственно ответ на вопрос, что, к сожалению, скорее всего никак.

Comment: Я не ярый сторонник работы только по инструментам "из коробки", и не брезгую либами, которые кстати не все поддерживает гугл, но ими многие пользуются. Вот такой вариант ищу.

Comment: Верю что нет ничего невозможного ))